# Check that two elements are conjugate

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Are the matrices
$\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1 \\
p & 1
\end{array}\right]$ and
$\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & q \\
1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$conjugate elements of $GL_2(\Bbb R)$? Are they conjugate elements of $SL_2(\Bbb R)$?

My solution:

For the first question, let
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc} a & b\\c&d\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ p & 1\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 &  q \\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc} a & b\\c&d\end{array}\right]$$
where $ad-bc\ne0$.

Then we have
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}a+bp &a+b\\c+dp&c+d\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}a+cq & b+dq\\a+c&b+d\end{array}\right]$$

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}bp &a\\dp&c\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}cq & dq\\a&b\end{array}\right]$$

So
$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}b=c\\b(p-q)=0\\a=dq=dp\end{array}\right.$$

If $p\ne q$, then $a=b=c=d=0$.

So they are not in general conjugate unless $p=q$. In this case, we have
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}dp&b\\b&d\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\p&1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&p\\1&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}dp&b\\b&d\end{array}\right)$$
provided $d^2p-b^2\ne0$, which can always be satisfied.

For the second question, Suppose
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\p&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right)^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&q\\1&1\end{array}\right)$$

Then by taking determinant, we have $p=q$. So similarly we have
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}dp&b\\b&d\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\p&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}dp&b\\b&d\end{array}\right)^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&p\\1&1\end{array}\right)$$
provided that $d^2p-d^2=1$, which can always be satisfied unless $p=0$.

So in conclusion,

(1) $$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ p & 1 \end{array}\right)$$ and
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & q \\ 1 & 1 \end{array}\right)$$
are conjugate in $GL_n(R)$ if and only if $p = q$.

(2) They are conjugate in $SL_n(R)$ if and only $p=q\ne0$.

Is the above conclusion correct? Thanks!

Comment: Both your first two matrices are missing an entry...

Comment: @Joanpemo Missing entries denote zero, leaving out elements is shorthand as well as improving legibility.

Comment: @McFry Thank you. In a two by two matrix?? Never saw such a thing. In bigger matrices yes, and if you check the latex encoding it really saves no time nor effort, in my opinion.

Comment: @Joanpemo Missing entries denote zero or arbitrary elements? In my proof, I assume the missing elements to be arbitrary $p$ $q$.

Comment: Just a comment: Rather than using `\bigg` to manually resize the brace, you *can* use `\left`. But you'll need an empty delimiter since you don't have a corresponding `\right` brace. For example `\left \{ [stuff here] \right.`, using the period `.` instead of the expected right brace.

Comment: Also, try `\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}` for matrices, saves a lot of the hassle (at least in MathJax).

Comment: @Mathaholic typically, missing entries denote zeros, **not** arbitrary elements.  This is likely what they meant since the $SL(\Bbb R)$ part only makes sense when the missing elements are taken to be zeros.  Moreover, the $GL$ part only makes sense when $p,q \neq 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to see that the elements cannot be conjugate for $p \neq q$.  In particular:
$$
\det\pmatrix{1&1\\p&1} = \det \pmatrix{1&q\\1&1} \implies p = q
$$
and any conjugate elements have the same determinant.

On the other hand, it is known that any element is conjugate to its transpose in $GL(\Bbb R)$.  Whether it is conjugate to its transpose in $SL(\Bbb R)$ is another matter.

Note, however, that these elements are only in $SL$ in the case that $p = q = 0$, so perhaps this is the case that we should consider.

Note that
$$
\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}A = A\pmatrix{1&0\\1&1} \implies\\
\pmatrix{a_{11} + a_{21} & a_{12} + a_{22}\\a_{21} & a_{22}} = \pmatrix{a_{11}+a_{12} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} + a_{22} & a_{22}} \implies\\
a_{21} = a_{12}, \quad a_{22} = 0
$$
It follows that we *cannot* have $\det(A) > 0$, which means that $A \notin SL(\Bbb R)$.

So, the two elements are **not** conjugate in $SL(\Bbb R)$.